# C# , Issue with writing HTTP content into FileStream, Cannot access a closed file

Tags: c#, multithreading, filestream, multipartform-data

I am trying to write HTTP content into a FileStream, and I get the error of "**Cannot access a close file**" at line where I do **await CopytoAsync(stream)**. If I remove the "**await**", it will continue the operation without any exception, however the written file size is 0KB. Any Idea where I am committing the mistake ?

```
   var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(tempdir);
     await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            foreach (var content in provider.Contents)
    {
         using (var stream = new FileStream(serverPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    await content.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Does the exception also specify which file is causing the exception? I wonder if the exception is caused by the access to the file in the tempdir or by the access to the file in the serverPath. 

The fact that you do not get the exception when removing the await is simple to explain: The method CopyToAsync is invoked but without the await the caller will proceed to the next loop without waiting for the asyn part of CopyToAsync to reach the part where it throws. I suspect the exception is still thrown but becomes an unobserved exception

Comment: @Ladi your suspicion about await is totally correct. The exception happens very randomly. sometimes for accessing the tempdir and often accessing the server path. I managed to get it done with the code I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue, by using the FileData property instead of Content in MultipartFormDataStreamProvider.

Also, I am not using the CopyToAsync anymore, instead I am using the normal File.Move and it works for me perfectly.

```
  var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(tempdir);
  await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        foreach (var content in provider.FileData)
          {
                File.Move(content.LocalFileName, serverPath);
          }
```

Comment: It worked also for me, strangely the FileStream and CopyToAsync of HttpContent doesn't work in an async scenario